# Cannot find module 'Express'; already installed locally and globally

Tags: node.js, express

I have a project that is using express for the backend API. The project is working on my local machine but when I try to deploy it on a linux VM I get the error "Cannot find module 'Express'".

The steps I took to produce this error were cloning and cding into the repo, and running `npm install`. express is listed as a dependency in the package.json file. I tried explicitly running `npm install express` and  `npm install -g express` and both said that they added and/or updated packages and did not return any errors. I also looked in the node_modules folder and there is an express folder there as well.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "user-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev-start": "nodemon server.js",
    "nvm-start": "nvm use 8.11.3",
    "postnvm-start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "helmet": "^3.12.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.2",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "slugify": "^1.3.1",
    "validator": "^10.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.1"
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: How do you _use_ it?

Comment: @tkausl I may be misunderstanding your question, but I import it with `const express = require('express');` and configure it from there with `let app = express();` and `app.use('...')`

Comment: According to your error message you're using `require('Express')` somewhere.

Comment: @tkausl You're right. I didnt catch that. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being a simple syntax error in my import ("Express" vs "express")